# Integrate UI + Functionality of one react app into another React App (like Google Maps API)

Tags: reactjs, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

I am building a dedicated react app for a functionality (lets say a currency exchange app which has the 'to' currency and 'from' currency and value, in a blue background strip). This app covers conversion for almost all currencies. Now I have a separate react app which is like a dashboard app which will house multiple tabs (currency conversion, distance conversion, weight conversion, date conversion, etc.). Now do i have to again implement the UI+Functionality of currency conversion seperately or is there a way i can just derive the whole UI & functionality of the currency conversion from my dedicated app? maybe like an API? This should bring the whole UI (blue background strip with 'from', 'to', and 'value') alongwith functionality (performing actual currency conversion).
Also, is it possible to limit the number of different currencies involved in conversion in the dashboard app, while keeping the full featureset in the dedicated app, maybe again using API calls? Thanks.